# Left align geom_text in ggplot while using Inf to define text position

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following ggplot.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x= c(5,2), y = c(3,4)))+
  geom_text(aes(x = Inf, y = Inf, hjust = 1, vjust = 1, label = "Label \nexample \n1"))
```

[image]

I want the label to be in the same position (i.e., x = Inf and y = Inf) but I also want to left justify so that each of the three lines start at the same x coordinate. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using another package is an option for you then you could achieve your desired result using `ggtext::geom_textbox` which via the argument `halign` allows to left justify the label inside a right justified text box:

Note: Besides some adjustments to remove the default box layout note that when using `geom_textbox` we have to replace `\n` by the html tag `<br>`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

base <- ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x= c(5,2), y = c(3,4)))

base +
  ggtext::geom_textbox(aes(x = Inf, y = Inf, hjust = 1, vjust = 1, label = "Label<br>example<br>1"), 
                       halign = 0, valign = 1, width = NULL, 
                       box.padding = unit(rep(0, 4), "pt"),
                       box.size = 0,
                       fill = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! When I follow this example everything works except there is a text box outline. Could that be an update in the ggtext library? @stefan

Comment: Maybe there was an update. I'm using `ggtext` `0.1.2`. One possible fix to remove the outline would be to use `box.size=NA` (instead of 0) and/or `box.colour=NA`.

Comment: Strange, I have the same version. Those suggestions work though!